# Generate random X and Y coordinates for a matrix, checking what is in that slot and deciding what to do

Tags: java, recursion, matrix, stack-overflow

Okay so here is what I need to do:
- Generate a random X and Y between 0 and 4
- Check the contents of a matrix at matrix[y][x]
- If it is empty, then fill it with an element from another array
- If it is already taken, then generate new coordinates and retry

My current code ends up in an infinite loop and my last version used recursion and gave me a stack overflow error.

The current version:

```
private static void placePrizes(String[][] board, String[] prizes) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            while(getRandom(board, prizes, i) == false)
                getRandom(board, prizes, i);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean getRandom(String[][] board, String[] prizes, int i) {
    boolean placed = false;
    Random r = new Random();
    int x  = r.nextInt(4) + 1;//JARVIS.random(4, 0);
    int y = r.nextInt(4) + 1;

    if(board[y][x] == " ")
    {
        board[y][x] = prizes[i];
        placed = true;
    }else
        placed = false;
    return placed;
}
```

The older recursive version:

```
private static void getRandom(String[][] board, String[] prizes, int i) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int x  = r.nextInt(4) + 1;
    int y = r.nextInt(4) + 1;

    if(board[y][x] == " ")
    {
        board[y][x] = prizes[i];
    }else
    {
        getRandom(board, prizes, i);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much to anyone that offers help!

Comment: *"Generate a random X and Y between 0 and 4"* - `new Random().nextInt(4)`

Comment: `if(board[y][x] == " ")` is not how `String` comparison works, you should be using `String#equals`; `if(" ".equals(board[y][x]))` or, if you can guarantee non-null values `if(board[y][x].trim().isEmpty())`

Answer (score 3):

Use .equals() to compare strings in java
Change your if condition and also check if its null

```
if(board[y][x] == null || "".equals(board[y][x] ){}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned there is likely an issue with the way you are checking whether a certain X and Y is empty (should probably be using `String#equals()` and depending on how the board was initialized either check for null or empty String).

Even fixing this I think you'll still run into the infinite loop, because you are trying to insert 21 prizes into 16 possible slots.

You do two nested for loops with 7 and 3 iterations (giving a total of 21 iterations). Inside the loops you pick a random X and Y using `r.nextInt(4) + 1`, which will give you a random int from (1,2,3,4), so you will have 16 possible X,Y combinations.

Lastly the second `getRandom()` call inside the body of the while loop is not needed and can cause unexpected behavior, such as causing an infinite loop even after you fix the issues mentioned above. I think you can leave the body empty.

EDIT:
Depending on the exact behavior you want, you can probably simplify the looping to be a single loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; i++) {
    while(!getRandom(board, prizes, i % 7)) // do nothing!
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
How would you propose I go about fixing this?

Comment: First fix the String equals issue, and figure out if you expect unfilled positions to be empty Strings or null (if you just created a String array then it will be null).
Next make sure the indices you're using are correct. You said between 0 and 4 in your question but your code is using from 1 to 4.
To fix the last infinite loop issue, you can simply make sure that the total number of iterations are less than or equal to the number of available X,Y positions and then remove the unnecessary `getRandom()` in the body of the while loop.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of one way to fix the looping issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you keep getting "false" of course you will keep getting an ininite loop

How do you get false? if the spot is taken. So if the table is fully occupied you will keep getting "false".

It has to do with how big the table is and how many items you are trying to store into it. If it's full you can put any more to it.

You could add a statement to check that the table is full and stop trying to enter new values after that

```
boolean full=true;
for(i) for(j)
  if(board[i][j].equals("")) { full=false; break; }
if(full) System.exit(0);
```